# IOS - How to a have a scrollable tableview header using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, storyboard

I would like to re-create the behaviour of the Spotify app for my personal app.

It's kind of a table view but the header view is dynanically sized. By default the header has his maximal size but when the user scroll the tableview upper side the headerview loose height dynamically until keeping its minimal size. The headerview should always remain visible.

here is the GIF showing the behaviour I am looking to reproduce: http://giftrending.com/public/upload/gifs/14827016661482701665.gif

By the way I am using autolayout with storyboard for setting up my views.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If possible can you post a gif showing the entire animation, its quite hard to determine an approach using before and after images! But most probably the behaviour can be replicated by using a `UITableViewCell` and `UIView` with appropriate animations depending on the amount the user scrolls by!

Comment: Show the code, how you determine the height.

Comment: The spotify app probably uses a collectionview.

Comment: @Rikh here is the GIF: http://giftrending.com/public/upload/gifs/14827016661482701665.gif

Answer (score 1):

This is not an optimised code, but you can try something like this.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return headerHeight;
}
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGFloat maxHeaderHeight = 400;
    CGFloat minHeaderHeight = 40;
    if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y){
        // scrolling down
        if(headerHeight < maxHeaderHeight){
            headerHeight += scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        }
        headerHeight = MIN(headerHeight, maxHeaderHeight);
    }else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y){
        // scrolling up
        if (headerHeight > minHeaderHeight) {
            headerHeight -= scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        }
        headerHeight = MAX(headerHeight, minHeaderHeight);
    }
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, i did some tests and It works sometimes but not always. Indeed sometimes, specially at the extremums of the table. There is a "return" effect that is not evaluated by your algorithm.  I continue my tests ^^